# Determine the charge distribution and the total charge of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

Suppose we have a spherical symmetrically distributed charge in vaccuum which yields us a spherically and symmetrical potential $V(r)$ according to:

$$V(r) = V_0(1-(r/a)^2)$$

for $r\leq a$ and $0$ otherwise.

We want to find the charge distribution of this system. My idea is as follows:

$$ \vec{E} = - \nabla V(r)$$

For which we then can use our postulate:

$$\rho = \varepsilon_0\nabla \cdot \vec{E}$$

So, $$ \vec{E} = - \nabla V(r) = 2V_0 r/a^2 \hat{r}$$

using the gradient in spherical coordinates.

The divergence in spherical coordinates finally gives us:

$$\rho = \varepsilon_0 \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left (2V_0 r/a^2 \cdot r^2 \right) = \frac{6V_0 \varepsilon_0}{a^2}$$

I assume this holds for $r\leq a$ and $0$ otherwise, but my textbooks says that we also have a surface charge distribution that's negative. I can't see how this charge distribution formula that I derived also can't hold at the surface. What am I missing?

I hope we can have a discussion on this topic so I can understand the concepts better since this is a relatively new topic for me.

Comment: Your potential has a discontinuous derivative (electric field) so the second derivative gives a Dirac delta. From Gauss’ law, this gives a Dirac of charge which you can interpret as a surface charge density. You can obtain your density either by using the boundary conditions for the electric field or going back to Gauss’ law on the domain bounded by the the two concentric spheres $r=a\pm\epsilon$ in the limit $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: @lpz Thank you for the explanation. Does this happen between any boundary between two different "materials"?

Comment: Not necessarily but generically yes. This is why between insulators, it is more convenient to consider the normal component of the displacement vector with respect to the interface.

Comment: Hint :  $V(r) = V_0[1-(r/a)^2]\,\theta(a-r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $V(r)=V_0[1-(r/a)^2]\theta(a-r)$ you obtain $\vec{E}=- \vec{\nabla} V(r) = \frac{2V_0 r}{a^2}\theta(a-r) \vec{e}_r$ and subsequently $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left[ \frac{2 V_0 r^3}{a^2}\theta(a-r) \right] = \frac{2 V_0}{a^2 r^2} \left[ 3 r^2 \theta(a-r) -r^3 \delta(r-a)  \right]=\frac{2 V_0}{a^2}\left[3 \, \theta(a-r) -a \,  \delta(r-a)    \right]$.

Alternatively, you could use the formula $\Delta \frac{f(r)}{r}= \frac{f^{\prime \prime}(r)}{r} -4 \pi f(0) \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x})$ with $f(r)= -r V(r)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Why did you put $\theta(a-r)$ in there? Is it because of the discontinuity at $r=a$?

Comment: @Tanamas $V(r)$ istself is continuous at $r=a$. The Heaviside step function $\theta(a-r)$ is there to express the fact that $V(r)=0$ for $r \ge a$. It is now easy to differentiate twice, remebering that $\partial \theta(a-r) / \partial r =-\delta(r-a)$ and $g(r) \delta(r-a) =g(a) \delta(r-a)$.  The discontinuity shows up only in the first derivative $E_r(r)=-V^\prime (r)$. The term with the delta function (related to the surface charge density) finally appears by differentiating once more, $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r^2 E_r(r))$.

Comment: Ohhh now I see where the dirac delta comes from. Thank you alot!